# Simple cross-browser image sizing

Tags: css, image, cross-browser

Let's say I have 3 images with these sizes:

```
Img1: 400px x 400px
Img2: 600px x 200px
Img3: 200px x 600px
```

I want them to be displayed **as wide and as high as possible**, but always with a **maximum width of 300px** and a **maximum height of 200px**, and obviously **keeping the image proportions**.

Namely, the images should be displayed like:

```
Img1: 200px x 200px
Img2: 300px x 100px
Img3: 66.67px x 200px
```

As a newbie in front-end development, I tend to use just:

```
img {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
}
```

And it works fine in modern browsers like Chrome, but it does not work in IE10, for example, where the image is 200px height but is wider that it should be...

So, is there any way to make such simple thing working in all browsers?

Answer (score 2):

use [CSS3-Media_queries#aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Media_queries#aspect-ratio)

```
  @media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9), 
    screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/10) 
     { 
    //your css here 

     }
```

This selects the style when the aspect ratio is either `16:9 or 16:10.`

EDIT:
(as because there was an edit in the question)

use

```
width: 100%;
height:100%;
```

apply a conditional CSS specifically for `IE8` or use the IE hack below:

```
@media \0screen {
  img { 
    width: auto; /* for ie 8 */
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know if I expressed properly. This has nothing to do with aspect ratio of the screen, I was talking about the proportionality of the image... I edited the question.

Comment: width:auto doesn't make any difference in IE10, and width:100%, height:100% works in IE10, but not in IE8...

Comment: +1 you gave me some good ideas. I'll wait for an ideal solution, if it actually exists...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS to fix this problem,

if image.height > image.width :
 then image.height = youdiv.height
else 
  then image.width = youdiv.width

I have done a similar thing in this project. You take look at that.
https://code.google.com/p/php-image-gallery-fullscreen/
code: 
https://code.google.com/p/php-image-gallery-fullscreen/source/browse/index.php

take look at the line number 100-115. 
Hope it helps you. 
(this code might not work for IE10[not tested] but i think, you get the idea)